# How to use different types on expression for ng-class?

Tags: angularjs

Suppose I want to separate the presentation from the controller. In particular, I don't want to encode any classes in the controller.

1. I want a class that is calculated (where I add model string to the class name):

   `<span ng-class="['my-class-'+model_value]">...</span>`
2. And I want a conditional class (where I show a class depending on a boolean condition):

   `<span ng-class="{'conditional-class': model_condition}">...</span>`

But how to combine the two approaches in one `ng-class` statement?

Comment: might try just putting first as `class="my-class-{{model_property}}"`, then use `ng-class` for conditional

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `class` and `ng-class` definitions independently:

```html
<span class="my-class-{{model_value}}" 
      ng-class="{'conditional-class': model_condition}">
...
</span>
```

The `ng-classes` will be appended to the original class.

Comment: It works! However it is not really satisfactory, because it uses both, `ng-class` and `class`. I thought I could do it only with `ng-class`...